# What is the meaning of some concepts in Operads?

Tags: operads

I have already studied the notion of Operads. As I am new in this way, I need some clarification of basic concepts related to Operas through examples.

We have the following notation:

- $\sum$: a set of symbols of algebraic operations $f$ together with their arities $ \nu(f)$

Let suppose $ \sum$  consists of one binary operation $ [.,.]$, and let $Lie$ be a variety of $\sum $ algebras. Then $ \sum ^{(2)}$ consists of two operations, say, $ [. \vdash .]$ and  $[ . \dashv .]$. How is $ \sum ^ {(2)}$ described?

What are operads $Perm$ and $ComTrias$ ?

How can we construct for example Leibniz algebras via $di-Lie$, where 
$$ di-Lie= Perm \otimes Lie$$

Example: Defining identities of tri-Lie-algebras is as follows:
An algebra from tri-Lie is a Linear space with three binary operations $[.\vdash .]$ ,  $ [ . \dashv .]$ and $ [. \perp .]$, $[ a \vdash b]= -[ b \dashv a]$ such that $ [. \perp .]$ is a Lie operation, $ [ . \dashv .]$ satisfies Leibniz identity and they satisfy the following axioms :
$$ [ x_{1} \perp [x_{2} \dashv x_{3}]]=[[x_{1} \dashv x_{2}] \perp x_{3}] + [ x_{2} \perp [x_{1} \dashv x_{3}]]$$ ,
$$[x_{1} \dashv [x_{2} \perp x_{3}]]=[x_{1} \dashv [x_{2} \dashv x_{3}]]$$.
I want to sort out of these example and appreciate your explanation on that.